# Kubelet in Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet

I wanna ask something cause I looked for it and couldn't find a clear answer about it anywhere.

Can kubelet be used in windows 10?
Because all I found is usage of kubelet in linux operating systems only.
Also what became my theory is that kubectl is the kubelet version of windows operating system maybe? 
I'm really confused about it and couldn't find any clear answer about kubelet in windows and about a comparison between kubelet and kubectl.

I'll be really grateful if someone could explain that to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add windows node to the Kubernetes cluster following the instructions from the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/#getting-started-adding-a-windows-node-to-your-cluster) page. As it mentioned in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/#getting-started-adding-a-windows-node-to-your-cluster), you can get all required components using the links from the Kubernetes [CHANGELOG-1.15.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#downloads-for-v1151) page:

- [Client binaries](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#client-binaries) (kubectl.exe)
- [Server binaries](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#server-binaries) (no Windows binaries, because windows cannot be master node at this moment)
- [Node binaries](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#node-binaries) (kube-proxy.exe, kubeadm.exe, kubectl.exe, kubelet.exe)

If you need other version of binaries please find CHANGELOG for specific version on [Kubernetes Releases](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases) page.

You need to have Docker engine installed on your Windows machine. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10) is the manual how to do it for Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

> Can kubelet be used in windows 10

`Kubelet` is one of Node Components and it is part of Kubernetes infrastructure. It is required to proper working of Kubernetes, so it is used in linux/unix, windows and mac.

> Also what became my theory is that kubectl is the kubelet version of
>   windows operating system maybe?

`kubelet` is an agent that runs on each node in the cluster. It makes sure that containers are running in a pod.
`kubectl` is a command line interface for running commands against Kubernetes clusters. More information ca be found in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/).

Please visit [Kubernetes Components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/) to get familiar with others Kubernetes components. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) you can find more information about `kubelet` and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/kubernetes/kubernetes_architecture) about K8s infrastructure.

> I'm really confused about it and couldn't find any clear answer about
>   kubelet in windows and about a comparison between kubelet and kubectl.

Those both cannot be compared. One is component of infrastructure, second is command line to execute K8s commands.

===

To run Kubernetes on Linux/Windows/MacOS you have to have container manager like `docker`. For Linux there is special package to download, for Windows is `Docker for Windows`. (Latest versions of Kuberetes also supports Windows Containers, but its different topic.)

To run Kubernetes on Windows, you have to use `Minikube`. It allows to run a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a Virtual Machine.

You can find how to configure Kubernetes on Windows in [this tutorial](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226).

Hope it help to understand.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it sure did helped me understand more about yet theres one thing I'm not sure about then.
I get that kubelet is part of the Kubernetes infrastructure but when speaking about the command set "kubelet", which as I've seen only being used in Linux OSs, can that be installed and used in Windows? And if so, how? I've been looking everywhere for an installer of the "kubelet" command set for Windows and all I found was for Linux OSs only.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read link I have provided? `Kubelet` is present on each node (no mather if you are using Windows, Linux, MacOS). If you have Cluster witn node, you already have kubelet.

In short in Cluster you have at least one node. Each Node in default have `kubelet`, `cAdvisor` and `kube-proxy`. Later you can deploy some Pods/Containers/Services etc. In this tutorial you have explained node related stuff https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-04-12-understanding-kubernetes-node/

Comment: As `kubelet` makes sure that containers are running in a pod (based on some rules which tells when when container is running proper and when not) it means that `kubelet` have own configuration which need to apply to it. 
You are not able to use `kubectl set kubelet`. If you want to change kubelet configuration you have create and apply JSON or YAML file like here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#create-the-config-file

If this helped please accept and upvote.